Apache Tika Server v2 Not Exposing Async or Pipes Endpoints
My goal is to use use Tika server to intake a S3 source/destination url to asynchronously parse various file types. Using this guide as a starting point I got Tika server (2.9.2) running locally using docker, but I don't see any /async or /pipes endpoints. I don't expect them to work locally without a bucket which is fine, but I'd expect the endpoint to at least show up. This is going off of their documentation on tika-pipes.
These are the only logs I get on startup and the /async and /pipes endpoints both return 404s. The main home page looks fine but also doesn't show the routes I'm looking for.
.
I'm assuming either I need to explicitly expose those endpoints, or it's not picking up on the jars I brought it and therefore not autoloading them. Or maybe something else I don't understand with the config file.
Any pointers are appreciated!
My tika-config.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<properties>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
    </parser>
  </parsers>
  <server>
    <params>
      <enableUnsecureFeatures>true</enableUnsecureFeatures>
    </params>
  </server>
  <pipes>
    <params>
      <tikaConfig>./config/tika-config.xml</tikaConfig>
    </params>
  </pipes>
  <async>
    <params>
      <timeoutMillis>1000000</timeoutMillis>
    </params>
  </async>
  <fetchers>
    <fetcher class="org.apache.tika.pipes.fetcher.s3.S3Fetcher">
      <params>
        <name>s3f</name>
        <region>us-east-1</region>
        <bucket>tika-bucket</bucket>
        <credentialsProvider>instance</credentialsProvider>
        <spoolToTemp>false</spoolToTemp>
        <extractUserMetadata>false</extractUserMetadata>
        <maxConnections>100</maxConnections>
      </params>
    </fetcher>
  </fetchers>
  <emitters>
    <emitter class="org.apache.tika.pipes.emitter.s3.S3Emitter">
      <params>
        <param name="name" type="string">s3e</param>
        <param name="region" type="string">us-east-1</param>
        <param name="credentialsProvider" type="string">instance</param>
        <param name="bucket" type="string">tika-bucket</param>
        <param name="fileExtension" type="string">json</param>
        <param name="spoolToTemp" type="bool">true</param>
      </params>
    </emitter>
  </emitters>
</properties>

dockerfile (I removed a bunch of lines from this part that were just downloaded dependencies, they are in the tutorial linked above):
FROM ubuntu:focal as base
RUN apt-get update

ENV TIKA_VERSION 2.9.2
ENV TIKA_SERVER_JAR tika-server-standard

FROM base as dependencies

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get -y install gdal-bin tesseract-ocr \
        tesseract-ocr-eng curl gnupg

# Set this environment variable if you need to run OCR
ENV OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1

RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-17-jdk

FROM dependencies as fetch_tika

# download all the tika dependencies (removed those lines of code for this question)

ENV TIKA_VERSION=$TIKA_VERSION
RUN mkdir /tika-bin
COPY --from=fetch_tika /${TIKA_SERVER_JAR}-${TIKA_VERSION}.jar /tika-bin/${TIKA_SERVER_JAR}-${TIKA_VERSION}.jar
# The extra dependencies need to be added into tika-bin together with the tika-server jar
COPY --from=fetch_tika /tika-fetcher-s3-${TIKA_VERSION}.jar /tika-bin/tika-fetcher-s3-${TIKA_VERSION}.jar
COPY --from=fetch_tika /tika-emitter-s3-${TIKA_VERSION}.jar /tika-bin/tika-emitter-s3-${TIKA_VERSION}.jar
RUN mkdir /config
COPY tika-config.xml /config

EXPOSE 9998
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "exec java -cp \"/tika-bin/*\" org.apache.tika.server.core.TikaServerCli -h 0.0.0.0 $0 $@"]

Then build + run:
docker build --tag 'tika_server_local' .

docker run -d \                         
    --name tika_container \
    -v tika_dir:/config \
    -p 9998:9998 tika_server_local:latest \
    -c ./config/tika-config.xml


I was able to solve this myself after I discovered if I tried to force /async and /pipes on, it threw a clear error stating that it couldn't parse the emitter config. I'm guessing without trying to force those endpoints on it just eats the error and doesn't enable them.
Force enable:
  <server>
    <params>
      <enableUnsecureFeatures>true</enableUnsecureFeatures>
      <endpoints>
        <endpoint>pipes</endpoint>
        <endpoint>async</endpoint>
      </endpoints>
    </params>
  </server>

I fixed the error by converting my emitter config to be more like the parser config (again my fault by blindly following the tutorial).
<emitter class="org.apache.tika.pipes.emitter.s3.S3Emitter">
  <params>
    <name>s3e</name>
    <region>us-east-1</region>
    <bucket>tika-bucket</bucket>
    <credentialsProvider>instance</credentialsProvider>
    <spoolToTemp>true</spoolToTemp>
    <maxConnections>100</maxConnections>
    <fileExtension>json</fileExtension>
  </params>
</emitter>

And finally something that was missing from the guide was in the json body of my request I needed to added an id field to the object like so.
[
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "fetcher": "s3f",
        "fetchKey": "presignedS3GetRequest",
        "emitter": "s3e",
        "emitKey": "presignedS3PutRequest"
    }
]

